# RegEx for matching numbers in Twig

Tags: php, regex, twig

I have a route like this

> admin/applicants/1111/view

I try to catch that route in twig like this:

```
{% if route  matches '#admin\/applicants\/\d+\/view#' %}
      route matched
{% else %}
      not matched 
{% endif %}
```

It should match, have tested and it works perfectly.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try this '/#admin\/applicants\/\d+\/view#/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Emma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989750/regex-for-matching-numbers-in-twig/55994521#55994521) is correct, keep in mind that you would need to "escape" the backslash in front of `\d` otherwise `twig` will translate to `\d` to a literal `d` in the source code

```
{% if route  matches '#admin\/applicants\/\\d+\/view#' %}
      route matched
{% else %}
      not matched 
{% endif %}
```

---

```
{% if route  matches '#admin\/applicants\/\d+\/view#' %}
```

Compiled PHP source

```
if (preg_match("#admin/applicants/d+/view#", (isset($context["route"])
```

As you can see the compiled php source translate just to `d+`. Adding an extra backslash "solves" this issue (see code above line)

Comment: I choose your answer than @Emma since it's more detail about what happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might just want to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, and it would probably solve your problem:

#### Code:

```
{% set route = 'admin/applicants/1111/view' %}
{% if route  matches '#admin\/applicants\/[0-9]+\/view#' %}
    route matched
{% else %}
    not matched 
{% endif %}
```

#### Output

```
route matched
```